# Adaptive bilateral filter in opencv python2.7 implimentation

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, imagefilter, noise-reduction

I want to use adaptive bilateral filter in python using opencv. But I am not able to understand how to put the parameters or what should be the values. This is what I found in OpenCV 2.4 documentation.

cv2.adaptiveBilateralFilter(src, ksize, sigmaSpace[, dst[, maxSigmaColor[, anchor[, borderType]]]])

Can anybody give me example for implementation of this function?

Comment: You might want to look at [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4476197/) which explains the filter and the parameters clearly!

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_bilateral_filter.htm

Answer (score 1):

Read this - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.02308.pdf
It has the math of adaptive bilateral filter. Let me know if you need help.

The kernel size is used for the local variance calculation, and where pixels will contribute (in a weighted manner).

sigmaSpace filters sigma in the coordinate space. The larger value of the parameter means that farther pixels will influence each other

For Example:
    img = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 20, 5)